# Vs 13 Nuget package manager taking forever to uninstall packages

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I've been looking around to see what support I can find relating to this but it seems non-existent for my particular issue.

As an example I started to uninstall jquery.datatables 1.10.10 from my project but after 30min it's still going.

The only obvious sign of whats going on is the progress bar seems to keep freezing in place for like 30 seconds before moving again.

Does anybody have any ideas what could be causing this or suggestions on how to diagnose this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was due to team foundation which actions were also running slowly and once I dropped about half the projects I'd selected it made a major impact on both.

Additionally I'll be reviewing my Workspace mappings in case that had a knock on effect which others seem to indicate it can.